# In odoo's controller file, how to change the json response format when the type is json？

Tags: python, json, odoo, werkzeug

The **application/json** in the request header and **json string** in the request body when I initiate an **http request** , the Odoo server receives the request, but the json returned to the client is not what I want to return.

Here are two additional key,`jsonrpc`,`id`,`result`.The dictionary corresponding to the key `result` is what I really want to return to the client.

And if I change the `type` variable in the `http.route` to `http` instead of `json`, I will can't receive json format data from the client.

What shoul I do?Thanks everyone!

My Odoo version is 10,python version is 2.7.12

Here is my code

**controllers.py**

```py
from odoo.http import Controller,route
class API(Controller):
    @route('/v1/access_something',type='json',auth='none',csrf=False,methods=['GET'])
    def access_something(self,**kwargs):
        return {"a":1,"b":2}
```

Test interface with `requests`

```py
import requests
re = requests.get('http://192.168.1.55:8069/v1/access_something',json={"c":1},headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
print(re.json())
```

The data in `re.json()`

```py
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "result": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    }
}
```

But the following result is what I want.

```py
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a way to solve this problem.

This problem arises because there is a method `_json_response`in the source code `JsonRequest`that we can overwrite dynamically.

In order not to interfere with the use of the original framework by others, we can pass our own specific parameters in our own decorator`@http.route`by using kwargs. We construct the json dictionary we need to return to the client by determining whether the decorator has our own parameters.

Here is my code`controllers.py`

```py
from odoo.http import Controller,route,JsonRequest

def _json_response(self, result=None, error=None):
    lover = self.endpoint.routing.get('lover')
    if lover == 'chun':
        response = {}
        if error is not None:
            response['error'] = error
        if result is not None:
            response = result
    else:
        response = {
            'jsonrpc': '2.0',
            'id': self.jsonrequest.get('id')
        }
        if error is not None:
            response['error'] = error
        if result is not None:
            response['result'] = result

    if self.jsonp:
        # If we use jsonp, that's mean we are called from another host
        # Some browser (IE and Safari) do no allow third party cookies
        # We need then to manage http sessions manually.
        response['session_id'] = self.session.sid
        mime = 'application/javascript'
        body = "%s(%s);" % (self.jsonp, json.dumps(response),)
    else:
        mime = 'application/json'
        body = json.dumps(response)

    return Response(
        body, headers=[('Content-Type', mime),
                       ('Content-Length', len(body))])

setattr(JsonRequest,'_json_response',_json_response) #overwrite the method

class API(Controller):
    @route('/v1/access_something',type='json',auth='none',csrf=False,methods=['GET'],lover='chun')
    def access_something(self,**kwargs):
        return {"a":1,"b":2}
```

The specific parameter `lover='chun'` is basis of our judgment.In method `_json_response`,we can get this parameter through `self.endpoint.routing.get('lover')`